# Is there a string function similar to "split()" that works for strings without a repeated character?

Tags: python, string, split

I want to split the ascii_letters* intoa list (in the string module) and it doesn't have any repeated characters. I tried to put the split marker as '' but that didn't work; I got an ValueError: empty separator message. Is there a string manipulator other than split() which I can use? I might be able to put spaces in, but that may become tedious and might take up a lot of code space.

```
import string
letters = string.ascii_letters
print(letters.split(''))
```

*The ascii_letters is a string that contains 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ'

Comment: Do you want to separate a string into characters?

Comment: A string is already a sequence of characters. In most cases there is no need to split it. If you really need a list just do a `list(string.ascii_letters)`.

Comment: You cannot split at empty separator.  It does not make sense.

Comment: @PramoteKuacharoen in some programming languages splitting a string on an empty delimiter *does* split the string into a list of characters. The idea makes sense (since it would make `.split('')` dual to `''.join()`) -- but it isn't python.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`list(letters)`

might be what you are looking for.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a regex to split a string using split() of the re module.

```
re.split(r'.', str)
```

To split at every character.

Or simply use `list(str)` to get the list of characters as suggested by @Klaus D.